# Setting private_key in r10k.yaml does not work

Tags: git, ssh, puppet, private-key

My r10k.yaml config looks as follows:

```
:cachedir: /var/cache/r10k
:sources:
  github:
    basedir: /etc/puppet/environments
    prefix: false
    remote: ssh://git@git.server:port/owner/repo.git
:git:
  private_key: '/root/.ssh/bitbucket.nopassphrase'
```

I run as root(for now) :

```
GIT_TRACE=1 GIT_SSH='~/sshv2.sh' r10k deploy environment env -v
```

sshv2.sh contains:

```
#!/bin/bash
ssh -v $*
```

And I get:

```
Faraday: you may want to install system_timer for reliable timeouts
ERROR    -> Unable to determine current branches for Git source 'github' (/etc/puppet/environments)
Original exception:
Command exited with non-zero exit code:
Command: git --git-dir /var/cache/r10k/ssh---git@git.server-port-owner-repo.git fetch --prune
Stderr:
trace: built-in: git 'fetch' '--prune'
trace: run_command: '~/sshv2.sh' '-p' 'port' 'git@git.server' 'git-upload-pack '\''/owner/repo.git'\'''
OpenSSH_5.3p1, OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013
debug1: Reading configuration data /root/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to git.server [<IP>] port <port>.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: permanently_set_uid: 0/0
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/identity type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/identity-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version SSHD-UNKNOWN
debug1: no match: SSHD-UNKNOWN
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.3
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Host '[server.name]:port' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /root/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/identity
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
Exit code: 128
```

Why is it not trying to use the key file provided in r10k.yaml?

I have:

```
$ r10k version
Faraday: you may want to install system_timer for reliable timeouts
r10k 1.5.1
```

and

```
$ git --version
git version 1.7.1
```

Am I doing something wrong or is my r10k or git too old?

Comment: Your ssh config does not appear to be setup to use the private key.

Comment: I assumed the config in r10k.yaml will force r10k use ssh with the proper private key. If I have to configure ssh anyway what is the point in the git: private_key setting in r10k.yaml?

Comment: R10k cannot overcome improperly configured ssh settings on a system. Make sure the ssh authentication on your system is able to use private keys. For example, start by checking if Kerberos is causing a conflict. Superuser may be able to help more.

Comment: When I change my sshv2.sh to have `ssh -v -i /root/.ssh/bitbucket.nopassphrase $*` I am able to get the environment without issues. Can I treat it as a proof that ssh itself is configured ok?

Answer (score 0):

The `private_key` setting is only used by the **rugged** provider and not by the default **shellgit** provider, hence why your script works with the alternate private key, but r10k doesn't.

The [r10k.yaml example](https://github.com/puppetlabs/r10k/blob/master/r10k.yaml.example) on github has more information about each setting.